# Loading static resources with custom directory structure in spring boot application

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a spring boot application that contains static resources in the structure indicated below ( `+` indicates directories, `-` indicates files)

```
+ my-app
  + src
    + resources
      + static 
       + v1
         + css
           - app.css
         - main.js
         - index.html
```

I have sub-directory that contains the application bundles. By default, Spring looks for **index.html** directly under **resources/static** directory. It does not find one in this case.

My index.html looks something like this

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/app.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Let us assume the application is hosted at `http://myapp.com`.

*I have two questions here*

1. How can I make Spring to look for `v1/index.html` under my static resources, when I access the application the URL `http://myapp.com`?
2. If I load `v1/index.html`by adding a view controller in ViewControllerRegistry, it does load index.html under v1 directory, but gives 404 on all the resources used by index.html (main.js & css/app.css).
   How can I tell Spring to get all resources from `resources/static/v1`, instead of `resources/static`.

Answer (score 0):

I created a basic Spring Boot Project in STS and did not any dependencies. I used your html sample from above and modified it to this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/v1/css/app.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

I created the directory `/src/resources/static/v1` and `/src/resources/static/v1/css`, placing the index.html file in the ../v1 directory which worked. The app.css file contained the following for testing purposes:

```
h1 {
    color:red;
}
```

This worked without any configuration changes to Spring. If you are using Thymeleaf, JTwig, JSP... you may need to add resource handlers or tweak settings for those template engines, I can't comment since I didn't use a template engine based on your example. Anything in the `/static` directory will be referenced without the `/static`.

I hope that helps, if it does please mark the answer as the right answer.